# Calculate the fee with conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables 1 is fee-structure and 2 is student-info, in fee-structure I have define all classes fee like..
Class tuition-fee  swimming-fee cricket-fee etc.

Class wise and in student-info I have a studenId(is primary key) and other-activities(in which he/she interested like swimming,cricket etc) column and in other-activities column I have inserted values(column name) which is defined in fee-structure and now I want to calculate the fee with respect to student I'd.

Main problem is when I m finding the column name of fee structure with the help of other activities from student info table it shows only that column name which is defined in other activities but as a value not a column.... I m totally confused to how to do this...

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. See posting hints here: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

More info on the tables definition would be very helpful.

Without that what I'd do is have two main tables: student and activity.

Table student should have, at least, fields: ID, NAME

Table activity should have, at least, fields: ID, NAME, FEE

A third table, called registration/interests, would record which student is registered/interested in which activity.

Table registration should have, at least, fields: STUDENT_ID, ACTIVITY_ID

Then, the query would be something like:

```
SELECT student.name, sum(activity.fee) AS total_fee FROM student, registration, activity WHERE student.id=registration.student_id AND registration.activity_id=activity.id GROUP BY student.name
```